# Show hint text in text field even if text field contains only spaces

Tags: flutter

How can I display a hint text in a `TextField` if it contains only space characters like `'  '`?

```dart
const TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'a hint text'
  ),
),
```

In this code example the hint text is only displayed if the content of the `TextField` is empty.

I need this because I need to detect when the user press the backspace button on an empty `TextField`. Read more here: https://medium.com/super-declarative/why-you-cant-detect-a-delete-action-in-an-empty-flutter-text-field-3cf53e47b631

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After diving deeper into the problem I found a solution with `InputDecorator`:

```dart
const InputDecorator(
  isEmpty: true, // if true, the hint text is shown
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'a hint text'
  ),
  child: TextField(),
),
```

So my solution is this:

```dart
String _value = ''; // state variable
...

InputDecorator(
  isEmpty: _value.trim().isEmpty, // override the default isEmpty behavior
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'a hint text',
  ),
  child: TextField(
    onChanged: (v) => setState(() => _value = v),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably, you should use decoration property of your TextField.
Something like that:

```
SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        width: 100,
        child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              label: Text('Your stable hint')
            ),
        )
      ),
```

Comment: This does not do what I want. If set the cursor in your example the text is no longer displayed inside the `TextField` where a hint text would stay. Instead, it becomes the label text at the top of the `TextField`.